# filter list of partial duplicates by condition(s)

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a list of partial duplicate records. Each unique record is identified by its first 5 fields, however each record has more than one "feature" associated with it, defined by the contents of the subsequent 4 fields. There is an "identifier" in the first field of each record, but an identifier can have more than one record associated with it. Example as follows:

```
A   1   122114  A   T   ABCD    c.123A>T    41  K/Y
A   1   122114  A   T   EFGH    c.456-7890T>A   .   .
B   7   56715   G   C   IJKL    c.321+9876C>A   .   .
B   7   56715   G   C   MNOP    c.543G>C    181 Q/L
B   7   56715   G   C   PONM    c.-7324G>C  .   .
C   12  9844    T   C   QRST    c.8392-68723T>C .   .
C   12  3338745 T   C   UVWX    c.599A>G    200 P/*
C   21  71120   C   G   YZAB    c.35C>G 12  D
C   21  71120   C   G   CDEF    c.-2345G>C  .   .
D   1   122114  A   T   ABCD    c.123A>T    41  K/Y
D   1   122114  A   T   EFGH    c.456-7890T>A   .   .
E   8   5094    A   AT  GHIJ    c.678_679insT   226-227 .
E   8   5094    A   AT  KLMN    c.-2356_-2357insT   .   .
```

I wish to filter the file down to one line for each "record", using a hierarchy of conditions to filter the "features", for example:

- Field 9 contains "/", or else
- Field 9 contains [A-Z], or else
- Field 8 contains [digit], or else
- Field 7 contains "[range from -50 to +50][A,C,T or G]"

Once a "record" meets these conditions, I do not wish it further (to avoid getting more than one line per "record").

I've tried using awk to create an array using the first 5 fields and running a for loop but I'm making a bit of a hash of it (excuse the pun):

```
awk -F"\t" '{a[$1$2$3$4$5]=$0;{for (i in a) if ($9~"/") print a[i]; else if ($9~/[A-Z]/) print a[i]; else if ($8~/[0-9]/) print a[i]}}' file
```

This ends up printing duplicates multiple times. Is there a way to do this in awk?

Comment: could you explain more on `[range from -50 to +50][A,C,T or G]`? some have only one value, some multiple.. and `ACTG` matched immediately after number or anywhere in the field?

Comment: post the expected result

Answer (score 0):

Perl one-liner here:

```
perl -F'\t' -lane '$r{$F[0].$F[1].$F[2].$F[3].$F[4]}=$_ if $F[8]=~/\// or $F[8]=~[A-Z] or $F[7]=~/\d/ or $F[6]=~/\b(\d\d)[ACTG]/ and $1<=50; END{print $r{$_} for (keys %r)}' file
```

**Comments:**

A `perl` solution was offered assuming it is available on your system. If needed, it should be easy to rewrite in `awk`, given that the logic and syntax are very similar.

Conditions are based on your specifications, and `awk` snippet. As already pointed out in the comments, at least one of them does not seem adherent to your input file sample.

The **last** found record having the same key is printed.

The records are printed in random order.